# Select only the records with same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I am working on a SQL statement that will become a part of a view. What I need is to extract only the records that have the same unique key twice. The query looks like below right now.

```
select distinct 
    rscmaster_no_in, rsc_no_in, calendar_year, calendar_month, 
    Wstat_Abrv_Ch,
    h.Wstat_no_in, Staffing_Calendar_Date, payhours,
    l.OTStatus
from 
    vw_all_ts_hire h
left join 
    MCFRS_OTStatus_Lookup l on l.wstat_no_in = h.Wstat_no_in
where 
    rscmaster_no_in in (select rscmaster_no_in from vw_rsc_ECC_splty) 
    and Wstat_Abrv_Ch <> ''
    and h.Wstat_no_in in (103, 107)
    and l.OTStatus in ('ECCOTRemove', 'ECCOTSignup')
    and Staffing_Calendar_Date = '2020-11-01' -- only for the testing purposes. Will be removed later.
order by 
    RscMaster_no_in
```

The result I get from the query above is:

[image]

I need to modify the SQL statement so that the end result is like below:

[image]

How can I modify the above statement to spit out the end result like that?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Pictures of data make it harder to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the analytic [`count(*) over ()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
with cte as (
  select
      count(*) over (partition by YourUniqueKey) as MyRowCount
  {rest of your query}
)
select *
from cte
where MyRowCount = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the results you want (performance is dependent on indexes/table design).

This takes your core logic and puts it into a sub select that only returns records that have a count > 1.

Then use those ID's to select all the data you need but only for those ID's that are in the sub select with count > 1

```
select distinct rscmaster_no_in,rsc_no_in, calendar_year, calendar_month, 
Wstat_Abrv_Ch, h.Wstat_no_in, Staffing_Calendar_Date, payhours ,l.OTStatus
from vw_all_ts_hire h
left join MCFRS_OTStatus_Lookup l on l.wstat_no_in = h.Wstat_no_in
WHERE rscmaster_no_in IN (
    SELECT rscmaster_no_in
    from vw_all_ts_hire h
    left join MCFRS_OTStatus_Lookup l on l.wstat_no_in = h.Wstat_no_in
    where rscmaster_no_in in (select rscmaster_no_in from vw_rsc_ECC_splty) 
    and Wstat_Abrv_Ch <> ''
    and h.Wstat_no_in in (103, 107)
    and l.OTStatus in ('ECCOTRemove', 'ECCOTSignup')
    and Staffing_Calendar_Date = '2020-11-01' -- only for the testing purposes. Will be removed later.
    GROUP BY rscmaster_no_in
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) 
order by RscMaster_no_in
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(*) OVER ()` window function such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rscmaster_no_in) AS cnt,
          t.*
     FROM tab t
   ) t
 WHERE cnt>1
   AND OTStatus = 'ECCOTRemove'
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
select * from (
select distinct 
    rscmaster_no_in, rsc_no_in, calendar_year, calendar_month, 
    Wstat_Abrv_Ch,
    h.Wstat_no_in, Staffing_Calendar_Date, payhours,
    l.OTStatus,
    SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rscmaster_no_in) AS uinqueCount
from 
    vw_all_ts_hire h
left join 
    MCFRS_OTStatus_Lookup l on l.wstat_no_in = h.Wstat_no_in
where 
    rscmaster_no_in in (select rscmaster_no_in from vw_rsc_ECC_splty) 
    and Wstat_Abrv_Ch <> ''
    and h.Wstat_no_in in (103, 107)
    and l.OTStatus in ('ECCOTRemove', 'ECCOTSignup')
    and Staffing_Calendar_Date = '2020-11-01' -- only for the testing purposes. Will be removed later.
) innerReult
where uinqueCount=2 --Or uinqueCount>1 base on your business
order by 
    RscMaster_no_in
```

Comment: How is this different/better than the existing 3 answers?

Comment: This is the complete answer base on question.The other answers talk about how you can approach,but this answer show how you can use it in current question